# Combining two services - Design Pattern MVC

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have a service that locks the user from doing actions on an Id, called "LockingService",

I also have 2 different things that need to be locked:

1. (MembershipService) Login - if a user tried to login with a membership number more than 3 times - the membership number is locked.
2. (OtherService) If a user tried to put invalid credentials - their session is locked.

The service doesn't distinguish the two.

Described is one of the flows (for the login) that currently exists on the controller:

```
if(LockingService.IsLocked(membershipNumber)) 
   return View(dto);


if(MembershipService.login(membershipNumber)) {
   ... some actions that always
   return dto;
}
else {
   LockingService.AddToFailedAttempts(membershipNumber);
   return dto; // with errors
}
```

I believe this flow an logic should not reside in the controller.

Suggestions of general comments would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This looks more like a code review

Comment: It is not. Its how the developer who wrote the code suggested implementation in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - this does not belongs to controller, it belongs to service.

You should have i.e. UserService that has method login with business logic inside.

The service can use other services, just require them and use them. The controller should just handle input/output and call the proper service method.

Comment: Any specific design patterns that would be suitable?